# Как задать настройки компилятора в Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, gcc, qtcreator, arm

Возникла проблема при сборке проекта под arm (embedded). Я указал путь к компилятору `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` и все `.c`-файлы компилируются нормально, а файлы ассемблера - нет. Если файл ассемблера имеет расширение `.asm`, то он игнорируется. Если файл ассемблера имеет расширение `.s`, то почему-то запускается программа `arm-none-eabi-as.exe` с ключами, характерными для gcc. Отдельно компилятор ассемблера в комплекте задать невозможно. Вопрос: сделать, чтобы Qt Creator запускал программу `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe` для файлов ассемблера? Проект управляется системой qbs.

[image: Настройка комплекта]

[image: Настройка компилятора]

Comment: так вы покажите qbs файл свой, возможно и подскажу что нибудь.
у меня все прекрасно работает